# Searching for a new home for my svn repos - need your suggestions

Tags: svn, repository, hosting, provider

**Please read first before you vote me down for no reason** (three downvotes in half a minute - shock) - I really don't know where on stackexchange does my question belongs to. They're saying to be a network of 101 QA sites so no idea and this seems to be a mixed question that is hard to categorize at the first glance. 
Personaly I think it belongs here. Though I'm a coder not an admin so I'm interested in other programmers opinion. We all are using some kind of versioning software and have to store our repository's somewhere. This is what I'm looking for.

### Question:

I'm searching for a good and reliable online hoster for my private svn repositories . Till today I'm using my company's server. The good is that it's for free. The bad that this server is being disconnected every evening. Always when I've got the time to work on my projects the server's down ;/.

So I think that it'll be the best to find an online subversion provider because I really prefer a hand free solution over fiddling around with my own webserver. So far I know what I want, but I'm shocked how many provider's are existing. In **[THIS LIST](http://www.svnhostingcomparison.com/)** are over one hundred names!

Ok, this can be filtered but (in my case the fee of 10$ or less per month) but even then the list stays very long and I definitely have no clue which one I should pick. Like everyone I would tend to one of the names I heard before **Unfuddle, Beanstalk, CodeSpaces or CloudForge **... but are they really good? No idea.

In most cases you only can answer this when you allready using this provider for a while to know all it's goods and pitfalls.

**Please share your experiences with me.** Which provider is the one for you and why? I'm thankful for every recommendation you could give me.

Comment: I'm afraid this question does not belong to Stack Overflow (technical question only) .

Comment: **-3 in half a minute??? Is it what you would call a fair behavior?**

Comment: Georgesl Thank your for commenting - I'm glad that someone gives me a hint what's going on. **But where does this question belongs to?** I'm new to stackoverflow so how should I know?

Comment: frankly I don't know : the Stack exchange network is here to answer precise questions; it is not a place for subjective view (on SVN hosts for example). You can try on http://programmers.stackexchange.com/ though.

Comment: Just read the line on stackexchange that says "...fast-growing network of 101 question and answer sites" ... OK, this is very confusing. Programmers seems to be about conceptual programming, stack fault for admins, webmasters obviously for webmasters. Damn it, I'm a programmer and search just for the home for my repos ;(

Comment: @Hexodus - don't forget gamedev, for game development; or codereview for code reviews. I have to agree - too many sites.

Comment: FYI, using your company's "free" server for your personal repository was *never* good. Don't ever mix personal work with what you do for your employer - the two should never touch the same computers, and you  shouldn't be doing personal project on company time/resources. You're fortunate that the company hasn't yet asserted a claim to those repository contents - don't mention it to them *ever* in the future, else you may face it then.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have no practical experience using any of the SAAS you mentioned above. However, I know that you can buy a cheap (around $5/m) shared hosting out there and setup your own svn on the server. You still need to ask for an SSH access to the server to install svn though, but that shouldn't be a problem as most shared hosting websites will give you access once you send them an email or sometimes they require you calling them to verify you're the hosting  main owner for security purposes.

If you are not comfortable with shared hosting, you know that you can host your private code for as little as $7 per month on GitHub, SourceForge, etc. Check it out:
https://github.com/features/hosting

Comment: I allready have a github account but I thought that github ist **Git-only** or not?

Answer (score 1):

I use [Project Locker](http://www.projectlocker.com/). It has been reliable for me. I am on a paid plan, but I notice they have a free plan with limited users/ projects. This may be enough for you.

What I would do when looking at a provider is to look at the total package that they offer. The Source Control service is the commodity - everyone has it, so you have to look at what other value you will get:

1. Make sure your provider allows you to take a backup of your repo - you might want to move your repo in the future, so you will want this.
2. Some providers include a bug tracker, which you may find useful.
3. Some providers integrate with third party project management tools.
4. etc... It depends on what you are looking for.

One other note - some providers will give you a free trial. Take advantage of that to see if that  provider will work for you.

Comment: These are good points. I never thought that making backups may be a problem.   

Project locker seems to be really straight forward and got a free plan - I may sign up there for a trail.

Answer (score 1):

Check out Assembla. They are my personal favorite for SVN. Free private repos, nice web features, and reliable. http://www.assembla.com

Comment: This one looks fine though the word **team** is very emphasized on the webpage. Anyways I'll take a closer look at it.